# react material-ui table search

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TablePagination from "@material-ui/core/TablePagination";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import { EnhancedTableToolbar } from "./EnhancedTableToolbars";
import EnhancedTableHead from "./EnhancedTableHeads";

function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
  return order === "desc"
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}

function stableSort(array, comparator) {
  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) return order;
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  paper: {
    width: "100%",
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: "200px",
  },
  visuallyHidden: {
    border: 0,
    clip: "rect(0 0 0 0)",
    height: 1,
    margin: -1,
    overflow: "hidden",
    padding: 0,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 20,
    width: 1,
  },
}));

export default function EnhancedTable() {
  const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Leesang",
      age: "25",
      Gender: "Genderder",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "chldms",
      age: "27",
      Gender: "Genderder",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "dlsmzl",
      age: "11",
      Gender: "Genderder",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "dlsmcl",
      age: "35",
      Gender: "Genderder",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "sdafldsm",
      age: "25",
      Gender: "Genderder",
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "lsdmafas",
      age: "27",
      Gender: "Genderder",
    },
  ];
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(data);

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [order, setOrder] = React.useState("asc");
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState("Age");
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [dense, setDense] = React.useState(false);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);
  console.log(selected);
  const handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
    const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
    setOrder(isAsc ? "desc" : "asc");
    setOrderBy(property);
  };

  const handleSelectAllClick = (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      const newSelecteds = rows.map((n) => n.id);
      setSelected(newSelecteds);
      return;
    }
    setSelected([]);
  };

  const handleClick = (event, id) => {
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(id);
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, id);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1)
      );
    }

    setSelected(newSelected);
  };

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
    setPage(0);
  };

  const handleChangeDense = (event) => {
    setDense(event.target.checked);
  };

  const isSelected = (name) => selected.indexOf(name) !== -1;

  const emptyRows =
    rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, rows.length - page * rowsPerPage);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <EnhancedTableToolbar
          rows={rows}
          setRows={setRows}
          selected={selected}
          numSelected={selected.length}
        />
        <TableContainer>
          <Table
            className={classes.table}
            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
            size={dense ? "small" : "medium"}
            aria-label="enhanced table"
          >
            <EnhancedTableHead
              classes={classes}
              numSelected={selected.length}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={rows.length}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map((row, index) => {
                  const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.id);
                  const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover
                      onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.id)}
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={row.id}
                      selected={isItemSelected}
                    >
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                        <Checkbox
                          checked={isItemSelected}
                          inputProps={{ "aria-labelledby": labelId }}
                        />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell
                        component="th"
                        id={labelId}
                        scope="row"
                        padding="none"
                      >
                        {row.name}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.age}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.Gender}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow style={{ height: (dense ? 33 : 53) * emptyRows }}>
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        <TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
          component="div"
          count={rows.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          onChangePage={handleChangePage}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </Paper>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Switch checked={dense} onChange={handleChangeDense} />}
        label="Dense padding"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableSortLabel from "@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
const headCells = [
  {
    id: "name",
    numeric: false,
    disablePadding: true,
    label: "Dessert (100g serving)",
  },
  { id: "age", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "age" },
  { id: "Gender", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Gender" },
];

function EnhancedTableHead(props) {
  const {
    classes,
    onSelectAllClick,
    order,
    orderBy,
    numSelected,
    rowCount,
    onRequestSort,
  } = props;
  const createSortHandler = (property) => (event) => {
    onRequestSort(event, property);
  };

  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
          <Checkbox
            indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount}
            checked={rowCount > 0 && numSelected === rowCount}
            onChange={onSelectAllClick}
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "select all desserts" }}
          />
        </TableCell>
        {headCells.map((headCell) => (
          <TableCell
            key={headCell.id}
            align={headCell.numeric ? "right" : "left"}
            padding={headCell.disablePadding ? "none" : "default"}
            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
          >
            <TableSortLabel
              active={orderBy === headCell.id}
              direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
              onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
            >
              {headCell.label}
              {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                <span className={classes.visuallyHidden}>
                  {order === "desc" ? "sorted descending" : "sorted ascending"}
                </span>
              ) : null}
            </TableSortLabel>
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
}

EnhancedTableHead.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  onRequestSort: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onSelectAllClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  order: PropTypes.oneOf(["asc", "desc"]).isRequired,
  orderBy: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  rowCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};
export default EnhancedTableHead;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import clsx from "clsx";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import FilterListIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FilterList";
import { lighten, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles as inputMakeStyled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
const useToolbarStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
    paddingRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  highlight:
    theme.palette.type === "light"
      ? {
          color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
          backgroundColor: lighten(theme.palette.secondary.light, 0.85),
        }
      : {
          color: theme.palette.text.primary,
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark,
        },
  title: {
    flex: "1 1 100%",
  },
}));
const useStyles = inputMakeStyled((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "25ch",
    },
  },
}));
export const EnhancedTableToolbar = (props) => {
  const classes = useToolbarStyles();
  const inputClasses = useStyles();
  const { numSelected, selected, setRows, rows } = props;
  const [selecNum, setSelecNum] = useState(numSelected);
  useEffect(() => {
    setSelecNum(numSelected);
  }, [numSelected]);
  const onRemove = () => {
    const reMoveRow = rows.filter((row) => !selected.includes(row.id));

    setRows(reMoveRow);
    setSelecNum(0);
  };
  return (
    <Toolbar
      className={clsx(classes.root, {
        [classes.highlight]: selecNum > 0,
      })}
    >
      {selecNum > 0 ? (
        <Typography
          className={classes.title}
          color="inherit"
          variant="subtitle1"
          component="div"
        >
          {selecNum} selected
        </Typography>
      ) : (
        <Typography
          className={classes.title}
          variant="h6"
          id="tableTitle"
          component="div"
        >
          Nutrition
        </Typography>
      )}
      <form className={inputClasses.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Search" variant="outlined" />
      </form>
      {selecNum > 0 ? (
        <Tooltip title="Delete">
          <IconButton onClick={onRemove} aria-label="delete">
            <DeleteIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      ) : (
        <Tooltip title="Filter list">
          <IconButton aria-label="filter list">
            <FilterListIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      )}
    </Toolbar>
  );
};

EnhancedTableToolbar.propTypes = {
  numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};
```

..........................................................................................................................................................................................................

### The code above is divided into three components.

I want to implement the table search function using the material-ui table. How do you implement the ability to search for data in a table? Is there an API with search function in material-ui? I couldn't find it. I need your help me.

..........................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Did you try material-table? It has the search function out of box. https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#material-table

Comment: I would like to use Sorting & Selecting on the URL site that you told me. Sitting & Selection
Can't you implement the search function in the ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are ok to use another package for material-ui table, take a look at this : [material-ui-datatables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-datatables)

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do this without using any additional packages.

```
// Search
  const [copyList, setCopyList] = useState(originalList)

  const requestSearch = (searched) => {
    setCopyList(originalList.filter((item) => item.name.includes(searched)))
  }
```

search component is like this:

```
<TextField
            variant='outlined'
            placeholder='search...'
            type='search'
            onInput={(e) => requestSearch(e.target.value)}
          />
```

and this is how I used the final result:

```
// this condition prevents rendering empty list

{(copyList.length > 0 ? copyList : originalList)
         .map(item=>(<div>item</div>))}
```

Comment: thank you for this answer, it helped me think my way through a similar problem and solve it in my app.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
import SearchBar from "material-ui-search-bar";
```

and then do as suggested in this example:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-ui-table-search-demo-x3viu